# Changing a variable though a module in a loop (java)

Tags: java

So I am trying to write a simple program for my Java class and I have asked the teacher for help however, this is a distance learning class and am not getting much help from that direction. So here I am.

The problem we have been asked to solve is to create a program that will
(1) ask the user for a number , 
(2) find the sum  of all user defined numbers ,
(3) find the average of these numbers , 
(4) then out put them back to the user.

I use the numbers not only to line through things I have finished but because they must be separate modules to be called.

How can i get the userNum variable to update durring the while statments. Currently they are not. OR is there a simpler way to do this that im overlooking. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
public class P2 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

        int userNumCount = 1;

        double userNum = input();
        double userSum = sum(userNum);
        double userAverage = average(userSum, userNumCount);

        sum(userNum);

        while (userNum != 0 && sum(userNum) <= 100){
            ++userNumCount;          
            output(userSum, userAverage);
            input();
            sum(userNum);
            average(userSum, userNumCount);
        }//end else
        while (userNum != 0 && sum(userNum) >=100){
            ++userNumCount;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Warning, your sum is currently over 100!!!!!"); 
            output(sum(userNum), userAverage);
            input();
            sum(userNum);
            average(userSum, userNumCount);
    }//end else
        if (input() == 0){
            output(userSum, userAverage);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Thank you for using this program have a nice day.");
    }//end else if


    }//end main module
    public static double input(){
        String userNumString;
        userNumString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your number or input 0 to end the program.");
        double userInput = Double.parseDouble (userNumString); 
        return userInput;
    }//end input module
    public static double sum(double userNum){  
        double userSum =+userNum;
        return userSum;
    }//end sum module
    public static double average (double userSum, int userNumCount){
        double userAverage = userSum/userNumCount;
        return userAverage;
    }//end average module
    public static void output (double userSum, double userAverage){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "The sum of the numbers input so far is: " + userSum + ". And the Average is " + userAverage + "." );
    }//end output module
}//end class
```

Comment: Oh right sorry, I seemed to gotten overly exited about posting just a moment...Fixed :)

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), please.

Comment: You need to keep the value returned by 'input()' whenever you call it. It would always look something like `userNum = input()`. That's one bug I see.

Comment: Thats how i define userNum, shouldnt that update when i call input()..?

Comment: Within the while line i ask them for a new number with the input() module, which then should refresh the userNum variable which is checked by the while loop again. This goes on until the user defines their number as 0. Or atleast thats how it SHOULD work... currently it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect.

```
public static double sum(double userNum){  
    double userSum =+userNum;
    return userSum;
}
```

In a basic pseudo-language this is happening each time this method is called

```
receive userNum
create userSum
set userSum = 0
add userNum to userSum
give userSum
```

each time the method will return the value it is given, not the running total I think you are expecting.

If you have two variables declared with the same name, they are still different. What you want to do is refer to the same variable, to do this you need to have the references in the scope where the variable is declared.

to get the running total

```
public class P2 {

    public static double userSum = 0; 
    //because this is a public member it's scope is global i.e. you can refer to it anywhere.

    ...
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ... 
    /* do not declare userSum here.
       if you do any reference to userSum will use the local variable 
       not the global variable.
       double userSum = 0; <-- declare local variable it's scope is until the 
                               end of this method nothing outside the method 
                               can see it but you can pass it as a parameter
       userSum = 1; <-- local variable is set to 1
       P2.userSum = 2; <-- local variable is set to 1 global is set to 2
    */
       input();// for this the input method is called and returns a value,
               // but you haven't said to put it anywhere so java will throw it away
               // all that effort for nothing.

       userNum = input(); // in this case it will put the new value in userNum.
    }

    public static double sum(double userNum){  
        userSum =+userNum; // do not declare userSum use it from the class context
        return userSum;
    }

    ...
```

}

for further reference [scope](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScope.htm)

Comment: If she want to to return running total then variable `userNum` also need to get updated.

Comment: SHould i do the same to userNum as well then?

Comment: I assume `userNum` was just your most recent input. If that is the case `userNum` is fine the way it is. Keeping scope as tight as you can is good practice.

Comment: See thats what userNum should be but the input() module isnt refreshing the value (I tested this by seeing if the if statement would take effect if i put 0 in for the input() module after i had used the input() module once)

Comment: Instead of `input();` try `userNum = input();`

Comment: @BevynQ Now i feel kind of silly...That worked wonderfully, atleast now i can exit the loop. The rest i feel i can fix myself. Thank you for all the help

Answer (score 2):

All of the values returned from methods in your main are just returning their values to nothing. When you pass variables to a function, they are passed by value. For example:

```
public void main(String args[]){
    int f = 5;
    doSomething(f);
    System.out.println(f);
}
public int doSomething(int i){
    i+=1;
    return i;
}
```

The value returned by `doSomething` is 6, but the program outputs 5. When you call a function the `int i` is recreated independently of f. As of now, your program is just throwing those values away and keeping the old ones.

Also you have the variables in main called `userSum`, and `userAverage`, and in `sum` and `average` you redefine these in a different scope. When code flow comes into sum and average it creates new variables for that method. If you want these values to be the same you need to make them static, by defining them outside of your main method and declaring them static.

I think the problem you might be struggling with is scope. Pretty much every time you have an opening bracket the program changes scope. When a block is closed (when there is a closing bracket}, the scope of the variables ends, ie. they don't exist anymore. For example:

```
class someClass 
{
    //Block 0
    static int staticNum = 0;
    public static main(String args[])
    {
        //Block 1
        int level1 = 0;
        if(true) 
        {
            //Block 2
            int level2 = 0;
        } else  {
            //Block 3
            level1++;      //ok because the level1 is accessible from here
            staticNum++;    //ok because staticNum is static
        }
        //resume block 1
        level2++; //not ok because level2 was in a different scope
        doSomething(level1)
    }
    public static void doSomething(int i){
        //Block 5
        int level1 = 0; //different than the one in the main method
        i++; //ok but once execution leaves i wont exist anymore
        staticNum++; //ok because staticNum is static and exists in the class's scope
        level1++; //not ok because level1 is not defined for this scope
    }
}
```

While execution is in a block, it can access any variable in blocks 'above' it in nesting level. Looking at the above, in Block 2 and 3 you can access anything in block 1 or block 0. Block 3 doesn't have access to the variables in block 2 because they are out of scope of one another, because when a block closes all variables instantiated in that block are freed. Block 5 has a completely different scope than block 1,2 and 3.

Block 0 is special because it is associated with the class. Anything outside of method bodies declared `static` are class wide variables, as in you can access it where ever you have access to the class. You would use something like `ClassName.staticNum` to access it in another class. Also when you access it inside of the class, any methods that you use the static values in need to be declared static as well.

Anything not declared static in the class body is an instance variable. It is associated with an instances of the class, these instances called objects. A class defines the template of an object. For example, lets say we have two objects of type Computer. The class Computer defines what variables each individual computer has(instance variables), and what variables every computer shares(static variables). So if I have Computer A with instance variables mouse and keyboard, it is completely different from another Computer B instance variables mouse and keyboard, but they can share a static variable called Computer.innernette.